# Как поменять функцию map на цикл?

Tags: python, map

Есть код, где содержится `map`, но я хочу заменить её на цикл.

Вот сам код:

```
def data(day, month, year):
    if day * month == year % 100:
        return True
    else:
        return False

day, month, year = map(int, input().split())
print(data(day, month, year))
```

Comment: Заодно можете весь код функции поменять на ``return day * month == year % 100``

Comment: а зачем?  в цикле обрабатывают однородные данные... а день-месяц-год лучше как то иначе обрабатывать и хранить...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def data(day, month, year):
    if day * month == year % 100:
        return True
    else:
        return False
day, month, year = (int(i) for i in input().split())
print(data(day, month, year))
```

Comment: строго говоря это не цикл. хотя кто его знает, что он называет циклом ;-)